# Red5Pro debug exception Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, video-streaming

I am working on Android Video Streaming.I found this examples online here https://github.com/red5pro/red5pro-android-app

I want to debug this application but its gives me error :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':Red5Pro:zipalignDebug'.

  > File 'D:\WorkSpace\Android\red5pro-android-app-master\red5pro-android-app-master\Red5Pro\build\outputs\apk\Red5Pro-debug-unaligned.apk' specified for property 'inputFile' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

How i can figureout this error ?

Comment: followed this? https://github.com/red5pro/red5pro-android-app/blob/master/SETUP-ANDROID-STUDIO.md

Comment: @tinysunlight its working!

Comment: hah ,the errorlog tell you all thing!

Comment: I am newbie on Android development also error text explain nothing for me.IDE and error messages different from Visual Studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

change third file'name to second file'name!

[image]